# Scala: show systemDrive in TreeView

Tags: java, scala, javafx, treeview, filepath

So I am trying out to show my whole "C:\" drive in a TreeView with JavaFX.
I have done it in a recursive way to also show content of subdirectories and so on but I am getting a lot of NullPointerExceptions and the files which are in the subdirectory also wont show in a proper way like to be able to expand it but just like its all in one directory...

```
    val rootItem: TreeItem[String] = new TreeItem(System.getenv("SystemDrive"),new ImageView(pictureFolder))
  //set a value for the picture of an folder Icon and use it for TreeItems
  val pictureFolder: Image = new Image("/fhj/swengb/project/remoty/folder.png")
  val pictureFile: Image = new Image("/fhj/swengb/project/remoty/file.png")

  //first set the directory as string
  val directory: File = new File("C:")

  //use the array to store all files which are in the directory with list files
  displayDirectoryContent(directory)

  //iterate trough files and set them as subItems to the RootItem "C:"
  def displayDirectoryContent(dir: File): Unit = {
    try{
    val files: Array[File] = dir.listFiles()
    for(file <- files){
      if(file.isFile && !file.isHidden){
        val item = new TreeItem[String](file.getAbsolutePath,new ImageView(pictureFile))
        rootItem.getChildren.add(item)
      }
      else if(file.isDirectory && !file.isHidden){
        val item = new TreeItem[String](file.getAbsolutePath,new ImageView(pictureFolder))
        rootItem.getChildren.add(item)
        displayDirectoryContent(file)

      }
    }

  }catch {
      case e: IOException => e.printStackTrace()
      case n: NullPointerException => n.printStackTrace()
    }
```

So has anyone an idea how I can solve the issue with the NullPointerExceptions and also why the files in the subdirectories aren't shown in a proper way?

Here is an image to this:
[image: How it looks like now]

Comment: You always add the files using this line: rootItem.getChildren.add(item) so they always at the same level; the root level. You can add another parameter to your recursive function that is the current level. When you add a directory, pass this newly created level down.

Comment: @Carl hmm that sounds correct but how do you mean one level down or up? Can't follow you what you are thinking of exactly?

Answer (score 1):

So I tried out something different and now my Code works, so it lists all the files of a subdirectory into that directory:

Here is my updated code:

```
    val rootItem: TreeItem[String] = new TreeItem(System.getenv("SystemDrive"),new ImageView(pictureFolder))

  val pictureFolder: Image = new Image("/fhj/swengb/project/remoty/folder.png")
  val pictureFile: Image = new Image("/fhj/swengb/project/remoty/file.png")


  val directory: File = new File("C:")


  displayDirectoryContent(directory)


  def displayDirectoryContent(dir: File,parent: TreeItem[String] = rootItem): Unit = {
    try{
    val files: Array[File] = dir.listFiles()
    for(file <- files){
      if(file.isFile && !file.isHidden){
        val file = new TreeItem[String](file.getAbsolutePath,new ImageView(pictureFile))
        parent.getChildren.add(file)
      }
      else if(file.isDirectory && !file.isHidden){
        val subdir = new TreeItem[String](file.getAbsolutePath,new ImageView(pictureFolder))
        parent.getChildren.add(subdir)
        displayDirectoryContent(file,subdir)

      }
    }

  }catch {
      case e: IOException => e.printStackTrace()
      case n: NullPointerException => n.printStackTrace()
    }
```

As you can see I added the parameter "parent" which always shows the actual parent of the files and where to put them in, and at the directory statement the subdirectory is set as new parent...
Altough I am still getting a lot of

> NullPointerException errors.

Has anyone an idea why?

Here is an updated image how it looks like now:
[image: WORKS but still with errors?]